# How to exit whole shell script while using the ssh

Tags: shell, ssh, scripting

We are in a situation where we got to check the status of the process over SSH and exit the ssh and script if the process is running and trigger an email if its not running

Below is the snippet of current script which calls status_email function in both the cases.

I am looking for your help to invoke the script only when the process is not running

```
status_email{
******
****
}

for hostname in `cat ai_hosts.txt`; do
ssh actional@"$hostname" /bin/sh << 'EOF'
pid=`ps -ef | grep <<Process_Details>> | grep -v grep | awk -F ' ' {print'$2'}`
if [ "${pid:-null}" = null ]; then
        echo "not running"
else
echo "running"
exit
fi
EOF
         status_email;
```

Comment: Isn't simply moving the call to `status_email` under `echo "not running"` going to do what you want. This is a logic issue, you are calling `status_email` in any circumstances

Comment: Here we are working over ssh and we don't have function status_email available in the remote server..Only solution i think of here is to exit the whole script when the process is running, but I am able to achieve this via exit commands..

Comment: You can store the output of the ssh in variable and later check it's value, depending of this value you can decide if you want to call `status_email` function. Let me know if you need example

Comment: Thanks for the update codtex, can you please help with an example..since the variable i store in the remote shell cannot be accessed in the local shell from where we are executing the script

Answer (score 0):

You can store output of ssh in a variable, then check the variable and depending on its value do something. For example if you save the following code in **remote-process-check.sh**

```
#!/bin/sh

host=your-host-name-or-ip-address

status_email () {
    echo 'Status email was sent.';
}

output=$(ssh root@"$host" "ps -C $1 >/dev/null && echo 'Running' || echo 'Not running'")

if [ "$output" = 'Not running' ]; then
    status_email
fi
```

You can use it like:

```
bash remote-process-check.sh process-name
bash remote-process-check.sh mysqld
bash remote-process-check.sh apache2
```

and if the process is not running `status_email` function will be invoked and you will see *"Status email was sent."* in your console.

The interesting part of the script is:

```
output=$(ssh root@"$host" "ps -C $1 >/dev/null && echo 'Running' || echo 'Not running'")
```

where with `ps -C $1` you are checking if process is running, with `>/dev/null` you are redirecting the output to the black hole and if command is successful, meaning that the process is running `echo 'Running'` is executed otherwise `echo 'Not running'`, which is stored in the variable `output`